# Finding shortest distance from a point to line through direction vector

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Find the shortest distance from a point $P(1,3,-2)$ to the line through $P_0 (2,0,-1)$ with direction vector $d = (1, -1, 0)$.

I know how to find distance between a point $(x,y)$ and a line $ax+by+c=0$ but I have no idea how to find it through another point and what & how to use direction vector.

Comment: Are you familiar with scalar product or cross-product?

Comment: I do know cross-product but not scalar product. I've tried searching this site and wikipedia but I haven't found a satisfying and clear answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cross-product: as you know, $$|a\times b|=|a||b|\sin\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $a$ and $b$

The shortest distance you require is $$|PP_0|\sin\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector $PP_0$ and the direction vector of the line.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

A point along the line is parametrized as

$$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{P}_0 + t\, \mathbf{d} $$

The distance to a point is $\| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{P} \|$ and finding the minimum is equivalent to finding the value of $t$ that minimizes the following

$$ \rho^2 = \| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{P} \|^2 = \left( \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{P}  \right) \cdot \left( \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{P}  \right) $$
$$ \rho^2 = \left( \mathbf{P}_0-\mathbf{P} + t\, \mathbf{d} \right) \cdot\left( \mathbf{P}_0-\mathbf{P} + t\, \mathbf{d} \right) $$

Distribute the expression before differentiating to get

$$\rho^2 =\left( (\mathbf{P}_0-\mathbf{P}) \cdot (\mathbf{P}_0-\mathbf{P})\right)^2 + 2 t \left((\mathbf{P}_0-\mathbf{P}) \cdot \mathbf{d}\right) + t^2\, (\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{d})^2 $$

$$ \left. \frac{{\rm d} \rho^2}{{\rm d} t} = 0  \right\} t = \frac{\mathbf{d} \cdot (\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{P}_0)}{(\mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{d})} $$

The point is found by plugging $t$ into the equation of the line

$$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{P}_0 + t\, \mathbf{d} $$

> In your case I got $t=-2$ and $\mathbf{r}=(0,2,-1)$

Answer (score 1):

The squared distance to any point on the line is

$$(2+t-1)^2+(-t-3)^2+(-1+2)^2=2(t+2)^2+3$$ so the shortest distance is $\sqrt3$ (when $t=-2$).